# What is the $\lVert v\rVert$ sign mean in the context of vectors?

Tags: vector-spaces, notation

Suppose $V$ a inner product space, $u, v \in V$.

I need to prove this identity:

$$\lVert u+v\rVert^2 +\lVert u-v\rVert^2 = 2\left(\lVert u\rVert^2 +\lVert v\rVert^2\right) $$

what is the $\lVert v\rVert$ ("two lines") sign mean? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the norm. In this case,
$$
\|u\| = \sqrt{\langle u, u \rangle}
$$

Comment: $|| u + v||$ is $\sqrt(<u + v, u + v>)$ or $\sqrt(<u, v>)$?

Comment: It is $\sqrt{\langle u+v,u+v\rangle}.$